# One differential problem

Tags: differential

Can someone tell me how to derive with respect to $\alpha$ from the following problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeEUr.png)

Comment: I suspect that $Q$ is linear and $Q^T = Q$ here (i.e. $Q$ a matrix). It seems to me that the answer would involve $b^T \nabla f_k$.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder that there may exist some typos